# Allowing inside traffic to outside on ASA 5505

Tags: networking, routing, cisco-asa

We have an ASA 5505 with an inside interface 10.22.33.0/24 and outside x.x.x.x/26. The inside ip's are obviously private and the outside ip's are public.

I've been able to set up a nat rule to route all requests to one of the public addresses to server1 with a private address 10.22.33.5. By adding this rule it allows server1 to get out to the internet too which is handy. So far so good.

What I'm struggling to do is to allow all inside ip's to get out to the internet. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: What's the problem/why can't they get out now?

Comment: server1 is able to get out, but all of the other servers on the inside (that haven't got a public address nat rule) aren't able to

Comment: Are you using the command line or the ASDM? You probably need a PAT entry.

Comment: I'd prefer to use ASDM if possible - I'd love to be able to use the cli but I think I might understand better in ASDM for the time being

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the Cisco ASDM, you have an option to use the "Startup Wizard" while retaining your current configuration.

From the main ASDM window, select "Wizards" and "Startup Wizard..."

Choose "Modify existing configuration"...
[image]

Step through the screens until you get to "Address Translation" page. For your setup, you want to use Port Address Translation (PAT). Use the firewall's outside interface IP. That means that all traffic not explicitly given a static NAT mapping (like your server) will be sourced out of the firewall's outside interface IP. You may need to delete your existing NAT rule before this will work. Re-add it after running the wizard.

Also see [this tutorial](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/cisco-adaptive-security-appliance-asa-setup-wizard.html).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your firewall does not know how to present the traffic from the internal (private) network to the outside (public) network.  It is likely throwing "Missing NAT translation rule" in the log when the internal IPs try to get outside.

Assuming you already have the ACL letting them outside, you need to set up a dynamic NAT rule for all inside addresses to NAT to a single public IP on the outside interface.  You first need to set up a global pool containing the public IP you want to use, and then set up the dynamic NAT rule for your internal subnet on the Inside interface.  This will cover the rest of the internal clients in one shot.

```
global (OUTSIDE) 1 <public IP> netmask 255.255.255.255
nat (INSIDE) 1 <internal subnet> 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: The above is only adequate to IOS version up to 8.2. It will not work on the IOS version prior to 8.3 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please check which version of Cisco ASA do you have:

```
show version | inc Software Version
```

Now, based on the version, assuming that the below are true

- **outside** - name of the outside interface
- **inside** - name of the inside interface
- **10.20.33.0/24** - subnet that the **inside** interface belongs to
- **10.20.33.1** - IP address of the **inside** interface
- **A.B.C.D** - IP address of the inside subnet is going to be NATted to (e.g. the IP address of the **ouside** interface)

you need to configure dynamic NAT entry in the following way:

- **up to 8.2**:

  ```
  global (outside) 1 A.B.C.D netmask 255.255.255.255
  nat (inside) 1 10.20.33.0 255.255.255.0
  ```
- **8.3 and higher**:

  ```
  object network anyname
   host A.B.C.D        
  object network inside
   range 10.20.33.2 10.20.33.254
   nat (inside,outside) dynamic anyname
  ```

That's all. Please, let me know if you'll need any further help.

Answer (score 0):

ewwhite's answer is correct but incomplete.  What's missing is the gateway information.  ASA's do NOT set the ISP gateway through the startup wizard, even as of ASA 9.2(2).4.  This is insanity-inducing because then no inside hosts can get to the Internet.

To set the gateway via the ASDM:

1. Login
2. Go Configuration->Device Setup->Routing->Static Routes.
3. Click the Add button (upper-right corner).  The "Add Static Route" dialog appears.
4. Select: IP Address Type: IPv4; Interface: Outside; Network: obj_any; Gateway IP: X.X.X.X.
5. Press OK, Apply, and Save, respectively

A few notes.  First, substitute your ISP gateway value for X.X.X.X.  Second, these instructions are based on ASDM 7.3(1).  Older versions of ASDM are similar, but may require some adaption.  Finally, "obj_any" represents the IP address of 0.0.0.0 and the netmask of 0.0.0.0.  If you don't have an "obj_any" use the 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 values.

To set the gateway via the CLI:

1. enable
2. configure terminal
3. route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 X.X.X.X 1
4. copy running-config startup-config

As before, substitute your gateway value for X.X.X.X.  If you do not know your gateway, you can easily find it by entering your IP and netmask on [this site](http://www.gregthatcher.com/Papers/IT/SubnetCalculator.aspx).